# Spring Boot RabbitMQ consistency issue

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I'm using spring boot (2.5.5). I'm seeing inconsistent behavior using rabbitmq queue listener.

Issue is, `accountService.incrementMediaCount` executes, even if `neoPostService.createNeoPost` throws exeception, thus executes multiple times, as retry policy is set to 5, which I guess seems weird as `accountService.incrementMediaCount` should execute only if `neoPostService.createNeoPost` execute successfully (without exception). Also, `loggingRepository.save()` execute lesser times than number of messages coming to queue. What is causing such behavior? Is it relared to distributed nature of RabbitMQ?

Queue listener

```
@RabbitListener(queues = [RabbitConfiguration.Companion.Queues.POST_CREATION_QUEUE], concurrency = "3")
fun postCreationListener(postMessage: PostMessage) {
    neoPostService.createNeoPost(postMessage.postId)
    accountService.incrementMediaCount(postMessage.userId)
    loggingRepository.save(
        Log(
            resourceType = ResourceType.Post,
            entityEventType = EntityEventType.Created,
            message = "Post ${postMessage.postId} created for user ${postMessage.userId}"
        )
    )
}
```

```
fun createNeoPost(postId: Long): NeoPost {
// Get post by id from postgresql
    val post = postRepository.findByIdOrNull(postId)
        ?: throw ResourceNotFoundException("Post $postId not found")

    val neoUser = neoUserService.getUserById(post.user.userId!!)
// Save post to Neo4j
    return neoPostRepository.save(post.toNeoPost().copy(user = neoUser))
}
```

```
//Increment counter in postgresql
fun incrementMediaCount(userId: Long, amount: Int = 1) {
    accountRepository.incrementPostCounter(userId, amount)
}
```

Rabbit Config

```
@EnableRabbit
@Configuration
class RabbitConfiguration {
    // other code
    ....
    @Bean
    fun retryInterceptor(): RetryOperationsInterceptor? {
        return RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateless()
            .backOffOptions(100, 5.0, 10000)
            .maxAttempts(5)
            .recoverer(RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer())
            .build()
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: `incrementMediaCount` is not transactional (I don't see any annotation like _"required"_ or so), also, check your transaction manager works and is configured for rabbitmq and postgresql

Comment: this method is transactional at repository level
`
@Transactional
    @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
    @Query("UPDATE User u SET u.mediaCount= u.mediaCount + :amount WHERE u.userId= :userId")
    fun incrementPostCounter(
        @Param("userId") userId: Long,
        @Param("amount") amount: Int,
    ): Int
`

Comment: I'm using one queue for multiple operations. Should I use multiple que with fanout exchange to perform each actions individually?

Comment: _"this method is transactional at"_ the transaction is managed by the transaction manager, your repo only said _"I'm transactional"_ but if you does not track the transaction level, you'll use multiple transaction levels and your behavior (my `inc` is not rollbacked) may occur. Of course, without a minimal reproducible example is difficult to say what's happend.